# Android efficient storage of two images which are similar

Tags: android, image, compression

Application size on a phone needs to be as small as possible. If I have an image of a sword and then a very similar image of that same sword except that I've changed the color or added flames or changed the picture of the jewel or whatever, how do store things as efficiently as possible?

One possibility is to store the differences graphically. I'd store just the image differences and then combine the two images at runtime. I've already asked a question on the graphic design stackexchange site about how to do that.

Another possibility would be that there is that apk already does this or that there is already a file format or method people use to store similar images in android.

Any suggestions? Are there tools that I could use to take two pngs and generate a difference file or a file format for storing similar images or something?

Comment: If you want to minimize the size of the image and you use PNG format you might be interested in PNG optimization to reduce size of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd solve this problem at a higher level.  For example, do the color change at run-time (maybe store the image with a very specific color like some ugly shade of green that you know is the color to be fixed at run-time with white or red or blue or whatever actual color you want).  Then you could generate several image buffers at load-time.

For compositing the two images, just store the 'jewel' image separately, and draw it over the basic sword.  Again, you could create a new image at load-time, or just do the overdraw at run-time.

This will help reduce your application's footprint on flash, but will not reduce the memory footprint when the app is active.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your idea of storing the delta between 2 images to be quite good.

You would then compress the resulting delta file with a simple entropy coder, such as Huffman, and you are pretty likely to achieve a strong compression ratio if similarities with base image are important.

If the similarity are really very strong, you could even try a Range Coder, to achieve less-than-one-bit-per-pixel performance. The difference however might be noticeable only for larger images (i.e higher definition than a 12x12 sprite).

These ideas however will require you or someone to write for you such function's code. This should be quite straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

An very easy approach to do this is to use an ImagePack ( one image containing many ) - so you can easy leverage the PNG or JPG compression algorithms for your purpose. You then split the images before drawing.